# ASUS SSD partitioning locked - how to wipe it?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

At the very beginning I have to say, I am complete noob regarding linux. Linux is blackbox for me. I am only selfeducated. I work on\with Windows mostly. Now to my problem.

Recently I came to Sandisk SSD 128GB, coming from ASUS ZenBook UX31 laptop, with unknown conditions. I purchased a simple adapter to SATA, since the SSD has ASUS proprietary 6+12 pin connector. The SSD seems to be in good condition, BUT!!! It has some 8 partitions (EFI, system, recovery, atc.) and I am not to get rid of them since its locked somehow and my windows tools were not able to remove it. FDISK, SDISK, DISKPART, any other partition tools...no go. I dont care about the data on the SSD, I want to completely wipe the SSD and use it as a laptop internal drive. Can you help me, please? Ask me anything you need to know to help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post a screenshot from Gparted.

Comment: Hallo, at the moment I am actually trying to wipe the ssd with "pmagic_2018_03_27" bootable USB. I used the Erase Disk tool to write  zeros to the entire capacity and btw., its 256 GB, not 128GB. It says it will take some 5 hours. Its 16:30 here in Prague now. I want to let it run thill the very end to se the results.

Comment: Before the current procedure I have already tried the Gparted tool that is also present on the USB. I tried to delete partitions but when I applied the changes, it ended up with some I/O error.

Comment: Generally said, I am conviced that the SSD is OK and healthy and is worth to try. Only its partitions are somehow locked by ASUS to prevent a user from scewing up the bootability and F11 - windows self repair/recovery ability etc. HDD Sentinel that I used to read S.M.A.R.T. data said the SSD is 100% and performing well. How do I post a picture to my comments? I will be back in couple of hours. THANKS, dadexix86!!

Comment: I made couple of pictures but I still dont know how to post them. Any advice? Or is it that since I am new here, I am not allowed to post pictures/attachments?

Comment: Post it on imgur or another hosting service and put here the link that they give you :)

Comment: OK, give me 5 minutes...

Comment: Pictures from Gparted live: https://imgur.com/a/d89YROR

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried to simply let it boot, just to try... I got pretty far! Evben on a completely different HW config including diffent BIOS etc., It booted up and entered the recovery. Then chose to refresh the device to factory  default with full format and no user data to keep. Only here the process failed, saying its unable to preceed with the refreshing... But this something I expected and I think its because of different HW. Any suggestions, to go on with linux tools?

Comment: In Gparted go to Device > Create Partition Table and from there you can create a new partition table. This way, you'll get a completely wiped out harddisk. Then you can create the partitions you would like to have.

Comment: WOW! i will try and let u know...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OzlQCj5

Comment: Its a no go ;o((( U can see, the program says something about the partitions being in use...?? Strange... the laptop was booted from USB flash, having the SSD only as a passive SATA drive. Then I clicked the "Ignore" button about 16x times (8 volumes times fsynch error + Libparted error = 16).

Comment: An input/output error is never a good sign. Can I see the detailed output of the SMART tests that you run?

Comment: Hmm, I/O errors...I know what u mean... R.I.P. Both the short (est. 2 minutes) and the long (est. 10 minutes) tests ended up incorrectly. They both ran out of estimated time but each test did not ended up automatically and I had to kill it by STOP button after an hour or so. I will try them again for you end paste some result if I get it. From my POV it looks like the SSD is really okay, only... read-only;o)))) I'll be at work now for 8 hrs, then there is Witchnight tonight and we go to party, so I'll able to do the test again about tomorrow evening. Thank you for helping anyway!

Comment: Hallo, guys! Sorry for long silence. But the good news is that I eventually unlocked the ASUS SSD in an older HP Elitebook laptop which has SecureErase in BIOS. It took about 2,5 hours to complete but in the end the SSD is still alive, no faults, fully operational and currently works as system disk in my hackintosh ;o)))